# Crawling case-insensitive URLs without duplicates

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm crawling a set of URLs using scrapy that are case insensitive, such that `http://www.example.com/ABC/1` is the same page as `http://www.example.com/abc/1`. In my CrawlSpider, I have a run that looks like:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(?i)http://www.example.com/abc/\d+', ))
```

which picks up both variants, but I end up double crawling the page because the duplication filter considers them to be distinct pages.

Is there a simple way to force scrapy to only visit one variant or the other (but not both), without subclassing `RFPDupeFilter` and changing the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` setting? Or is that the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy's rule class has an attribute `process_links` that can be used for normalizing all links to lowercase. In a gist:

```
def links_as_lower(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = link.url.lower()
        yield link

Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(?i)http://www.example/abc/\d+', ), process_links=links_as_lower)
```

Complete docs about scrapy's Rules are [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topi/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule)

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, but for the reference of anyone searching this answer, the function taken by `process_links` takes a list of links and returns a list of modified links, so the code in this answer fails as originally posted.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about this peculiarity - yes a rule might very well extract multiple links in one sitting and so the `process_links` method has to reflect this. Adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: `links_as_lower` still is wrong. You would need to set `l.url = l.url.lower()` for each `link` in `links` since `l` is a `Link` object and not the raw url.

Comment: Yikes! Sorry and thank you. Adjusted the code a (hopefully) final time after comparing it to a `process_link` method pulled from some old project of mine.